# How to replace sub query in a where clause?

Tags: sql, coldfusion, sybase, sap-ase

I'm trying to improve an old code that currently works with loop and updates two different tables. Here is example of the code:

```
<cfquery name="findStores" datasource="test">
    SELECT store_id, year_id, start_dt, end_dt 
    FROM stores 
    WHERE store_id= #storeID# 
        AND year_id = #yearID# 
        AND store_type_id IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)
</cfquery>

<cfloop query="findSubAgencies">    
    <cfscript>
        storeID= store_id;
        yearID = year_id;
        startDt = start_dt;
        endDt = end_dt;
    </cfscript>
    <cfquery name="updateStatus" datasource="test">
        UPDATE store_status
        SET start_date = '#start_dt#',
            end_date = '#end_dt#',
            last_update_date = getDate()
        WHERE status_id = (
             SELECT status_id 
             FROM store_status 
             WHERE store_id = #storeID# 
                AND year_id = #yearID#
        )
    </cfquery>

    <cfquery name="updateStoreDoc" datasource="test">
        UPDATE store_doc
        SET approve_start_date = '#start_dt#',
            approve_end_date = '#end_dt#',
            status_id = (SELECT max(status_id) FROM store_status WHERE store_id = #storeID# AND year_id = #yearID#)
        WHERE store_id = #storeID# 
            AND year_id = #yearID#
    </cfquery>
</cfloop>
```

Code above loops over `findStores` query and updates two different tables. I was wondering if this all can be done in Sybase SQL? Instead of looping over query and have two additional inner queries can we simply use temporary table or WHERE IN () to achieve the same result? If anyone have suggestions please let me know.

Comment: Like @ravioli asked, could you clarify what you expect the queries to do (not a description of the syntax, but what's the desired result)? What's the relationship between each of the three tables?

Comment: Particularly of interest is `store_status`.  Can there be multiple statuses per store/year? Why does the loop overwrite the start/end dates for ALL records with a certain status - instead of for a specific store + status.

Comment: As written above, your code doesn't loop over the `findStores` query. It loops over the `findSubAgencies` query. Is that a copy/paste issue and your loop actually goes over the `findStores` query? Or do you need to include the example of the `findSubAgencies` query? Also, those queries need `cfqueryparam`s.

Comment: @Shawn That is a copy/paste issue. It should be `findStores` query instead.

Comment: What columns are in `store_status`? Right now, the query will update `store_status` regardless of the `store_id`, it's only related by `status_id`.

Comment: And will `find_stores` return more than one result? Do you need to "loop" through those results?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the general idea (for explicit IDs):

```
declare 
  @storeID int, @yearID int
begin
  set @storeID = 1
  set @yearID = 2019

        UPDATE store_status dest
        SET start_date = src.start_dt,
            end_date = src.end_dt,
            last_update_date = getDate()
        FROM stores src
        WHERE dest.store_id = src.store_id 
                AND dest.year_id = src.year_id
                AND src.store_id=@storeID
                AND src.year_id=@yearID

end
go
```

Cycling through the stores:

```
        UPDATE store_status dest
        SET start_date = src.start_dt,
            end_date = src.end_dt,
            last_update_date = getDate()
        FROM stores src
        WHERE dest.store_id = src.store_id 
                AND dest.year_id = src.year_id
               AND store_type_id IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)
go

UPDATE store_doc dest
SET approve_start_date = src.start_dt,
    approve_end_date = src.end_dt,
    status_id = max_status_id
FROM (SELECT max(status_id) max_status_id, max(start_date) start_dt,
         max(end_date) end_dt, store_id, year_id FROM store_status 
      GROUP BY store_id, year_id) src
WHERE dest.store_id = src.store_id 
    AND dest.year_id = src.year_id

go
```

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen ColdFusion in a while...that `CFQUERY` tag brings back good memories :)

If you're running the same  `UPDATE` query for a bunch of records, you should run a single batch query (like you suggested).  To do this for all stores, you can use a variant of your `findStores` query as the source for your `UPDATE`s, something like this:

```
<!--- Update status --->
<cfquery name="updateStatus" datasource="test">
  UPDATE store_status tgt
  FROM (
    -- findStores query
    SELECT store_id, year_id, start_dt, end_dt 
    FROM stores 
    WHERE store_type_id IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)
  ) src
  SET start_date = src.start_dt,
    end_date = src.end_dt,
    last_update_date = getDate()
  WHERE status_id = (
    SELECT status_id 
    FROM store_status 
    WHERE store_id = src.store_id 
    AND year_id = src.year_id
  )
</cfquery>

<!--- Update store info --->
<cfquery name="updateStoreDoc" datasource="test">
  UPDATE store_doc tgt
  FROM (
    -- findStores query with MAX(status) calculation
    SELECT 
      st.store_id, st.year_id, st.start_dt, st.end_dt, 
      MAX(stt.status_id) AS status_id_max
    FROM stores st
    LEFT JOIN store_status stt ON st.store_id = stt.store_id -- Get status info
      AND st.year_id = stt.year_id
    WHERE st.store_type_id IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)
    GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
  ) src
  SET approve_start_date = src.start_dt,
    approve_end_date = src.end_dt,
    status_id = src.status_id_max
  WHERE store_id = src.store_id
  AND year_id = src.year_id
</cfquery>
```

I'm not sure if your underlying DBMS supports this syntax and how `Cold Fusion` will handle it, so it may need some tinkering to get it to work.

Also, what exactly are you trying to do in the `updateStatus` query?  You reference `status_id` in your `WHERE` clause, but not `store_id` and `year_id`.  By contrast, the `updateStoreDoc` query references both these fields in the `WHERE` clause.  I'm not sure if the query above will work properly for `updateStatus` in this form without referencing the table's PK.

And one last thing to consider is that the `store_status` table is being updated in the first batch query and then referenced in the second batch query.  You may need to switch the order of these queries depending on what end result you are expecting.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Sybase. Based on my experience with other database systems, the way your queries are setup even if you used a temp table you would either then have to loop using a cursor or do a multi-column join back on the temp table. Neither provide a benefit in the vast majority of cases.

With that in mind, unless there is some performance concern needing a temp table workaround you could just do the join on the original tables like below. I have not tested this so you should confirm logic before putting into use.

```
<cfquery datasource="test">
    update store_status
    set start_date = stores.start_date
        , end_date = stores.end_date
        , last_update_date = getDate()
    from store_status
        inner join stores on store_status.store_id = stores.store_id
            and store_status.year_id = stores.year_id
    WHERE stores.store_id = <cfqueryparam value="#storeID#" />
        and stores.year_id = <cfqueryparam value="#yearID#" />
        and stores.store_type_id IN (5,6,7,8,9,10);

    update store_doc
    set approve_start_date = stores.start_date
        , approve_end_date = stores.end_date
        , status_id = (SELECT max(status_id) FROM store_doc WHERE store_id = stores.store_id AND year_id = stores.year_id)
    from store_doc
        inner join stores on store_doc.store_id = stores.store_id
            and store_doc.year_id = stores.year_id
    WHERE stores.store_id = <cfqueryparam value="#storeID#" />
        and stores.year_id = <cfqueryparam value="#yearID#" />
        and stores.store_type_id IN (5,6,7,8,9,10)
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Yeah, based on what you described you shouldn't need temp tables, loops or cursors for this - just plain simple JOIN's.

Comment: More times than not, if you are doing an UPDATE and you want to use a cursor, there's probably a _much_ better way to do the query.